# Связь много ко многим. SQL Server

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть две таблици: Products, Orders. 
Между ними связь много ко многим. 
Нужно сделать третью таблицу Products_Orders с полями ProductID и OrderID.
Немогу понять как их связать и как я буду получать данные с таблици Products_Orders. БД SQL Server

Comment: В чем тут проблема? Вы сами все сказали))

Comment: *как их связать* CONSTRAINT .. FOREIGN KEY *как я буду получать данные с таблици* во-первых, запросом, во-вторых, именно из этой таблицы данные получать не требуется.

Answer (score 4):

Мне непонятен смысл вашей таблицы Products_Orders - что она должна содержать?

Если вы планируете держать там содержимое заказа, то она логически является дочерней от Orders, поэтому логичнее (и более привычно с точки зрения всевозможных примеров) назвать ее OrderDetails.

В этой табличке вам нужно создать, четыре поля (можно и двумя обойтись, если очень хочется, но это не очень удобно):

- ID - первичный ключ и идентификатор строки в таблице OrderDetails,
  добавляете на него PRIMARY KEY, CLUSRERED индекс и IDENTITY, чтобы не
  было необходимости руками заполнять;
- OrderID - Ссылка на идентификатор в таблице Orders, на это поле вешаете FOREIGN KEY со ссылкой на Orders (Id);
- ProductID - Ссылка на идентификатор в таблице Products, на это поле вешаете FOREIGN KEY со ссылкой на Products (Id);
- Amount - собственно количество товара в заказе.

Также можете добавить уникальный индекс на сочетание OrderID и ProductID, чтобы обеспечить наличие в заказе только одной записи с определенным товаром (количество товара можно регулировать полем Amount).

получать же эту информацию можно уже простыми запросами с join-ами.

типа такого:

```
select *
from Orders as o
     inner join OrderDetails as od on o.ID = od.OrderID
     inner join Products as p on od.ProductID = p.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

В целом соглашусь с комментарием выше, если вкратце:

следующий скрипт создаст нужную вам структуру OrderItems, которая будет создержать в себе продукты, относящиеся к текущему заказу

```
create table OrderItems (
    orderId int not null        foreign key (orderId) references Orders (id),
    productId int not null      foreign key (productId) references Products (id),
    itemsCount int)
```

для большей согласованности данных в этой таблице, думаю, стоит добавить ключ на уникальность продукта в пределах заказа:

```
alter table OrderItems 
add constraint pk_OrderItems_Orders primary key (orderId, productId)
```